# Dropdown Dependece Box not working when i auto click main drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery

auto click to dropdown select string working, but does not load dependence select box.

```
$('[name=appState] option:contains(West Bengal)').attr('selected','selected').click();
```

Comment: Add a mini working example of the script and html, so we could have a look.

Comment: <select name="appState" class="form-control">
<option value="1">West Bengal</option>
<option value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>
<option value="3" selected="">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
<option value="4">Assam</option>
<option value="5">Bihar</option>
<option value="6">Chandigarh</option>
<option value="7">Chhattisgarh</option>
</select>

*****Dependence Select Box****
<select name="appDistrict" id="appDistrict" class="form-control" required=""></select>

Comment: Edit your post add the working example, that inc the library, html and script.